# how to show one of the image with same id from database in php?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM news_events,news_events_images WHERE news_events.id = news_events_images.newsId";
$sqldata = mysql_query($sqlget) or die('error getting data');
echo " <table class=\"table table-striped table-hover\" style=\"width:100%;\"> <thead><th colspan=\"2\"> <h3 style= \"font-family:Georgia;font-size:22px;text-transform:capitalize; text-align:center; color:#ec1e2e; \">News and events</h3> </th>";
echo"</thead><tbody>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;padding:3em 0em;\">";
  echo $row['Title'];
  echo "</td></tr><tr><td  style=\"width:30%;\">";
  echo "<img src=\"Admin/images/newsImages/";
  echo $row['image'];
  echo "\"";
  echo" class=\"image-responsive\" style=\"display:block; width:100%; height:auto;\">";
  echo "</td><td style=\"width:70%;text-align:justify;\">";
  echo $row['description'];
  echo "</td>
  </tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

This code is displaying all the images row by row, but i want only one image should be displayed, In database i have 4 images under same id, from that i want to display one of the image

Comment: you can use group by news_events.id in your query

Comment: Then, Use `LIMIT 0,1` in sql query to show 1 image.

Comment: are all the images the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show only 1 image using same id then you group by

```
$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM news_events,news_events_images WHERE news_events.id = news_events_images.newsId group by news_events.id";
```

for more information group by

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp